# Visual Basic 2010 Picturebox1.Image ftp upload

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, picturebox

can someone show me an example script of how I would upload picturebox1's Image to an FTP connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do it with just plain .NET classes:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
            wc.UploadData("ftp://foo.com/bar/mumble.png", ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't you need the username and pass of the ftp?

Comment: Use `ftp://username:password@foo.com/bar/mumble.png`

Comment: can this work for download?  wc.UploadData("ftp://foo.com/bar/mumble.png", ms.ToArray()) also what if I wanted to declare a string (i have a gridview that holds ftp paths + filenames and upon selection it puts that pathname into a string would wc.DownloadData(string, ms.ToArray()) would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `PictureBox` has a source that's an image on disk. If it's not, find a way to save that image to disk.

Use this [VB.NET FTP client library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx?fid=225949&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=201) to upload that image to your FTP destination. It wraps all the logic needed, and will save you the time of writing the code yourself.

It uses `System.Net.FtpWebRequest`.

```
myFtp.Upload("C:\myimage.png", "/pub/someImage.png")
```

Comment: there is no source, its a screen shot.
Im trying to upload a captured screenshot to an ftp.
Do i need to make a temporary save first?

Answer (score 0):

```
                Dim username = "USERNAME"
                Dim password = "PASSWORD"
                Dim hostname = "http://www.wherethefilewillappear.com/directory1/"
                Dim server = "ftp://ftp.yoursite.com/"
                My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\text.txt", server &"/text.txt", username, password)
```

Easy as that.